# Full screen image over the container on Bootstrap 3

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Ok. I am trying to achieve a "Medium.com style" image alignment, making it larger than it's container and full width. I did what I knew I had to do with the CSS:

```
img {
position: relative;
left: 50%;
height: auto;
margin: 0px 0 0 -50vw;
width: 100vw;
max-width: 100vw;
}
```

It almost do what I want it to do, except that, when I use all the 12 grids of Bootstrap, for some reason, it adds a border on the left, as you can see in this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/35f4ntqq/

If I change the *col-sm-11* to *col-sm-10* (making it 11 cols in total), though, it works perfectly fine.

What am I missing here? Or doing wrong...? :/

Comment: Even if you are doing it 11 cols in total, it shows a horizontal scrollbar, if your okay with it then make your margin-left -53vw;

If its okay then I will put it as the Answer.

Comment: Well, yes it is. Until something better shows up... It just doesn't look right, you know? :)

Answer (score 1):

I think you can changies margin property for img tag:

Like this:

```
img {
  position: relative;
  left: 52%;
  height: auto !important;
  margin: 0px 0 0 -55vw;
  width: 100vw;
  max-width: 100vw !important;
  height: auto !important;
}
```

See [Updated Bootply](http://www.bootply.com/8m96O5ui7q)

Comment: But then I get a right margin (and the image is cropped on the left)... :/

Comment: Please replace "left:50%" to " left:52% " and check updated link.

Answer (score 0):

try this.
"medium.com style"

```html
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-1">
    Boo
    </div>
     <div class="col-xs-11">

    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam sed ligula nec erat dapibus ullamcorper. Aliquam egestas, justo nec dictum vestibulum, dui eros ullamcorper mauris, non facilisis lorem ligula ut ex. Mauris scelerisque libero nulla, eget luctus velit fringilla ut. Etiam ut magna eget elit gravida ultrices. Quisque a enim id leo tincidunt lobortis. Pellentesque nulla mi, aliquet non mauris et, aliquam egestas leo. Nulla convallis tincidunt gravida. Suspendisse aliquam lacinia eros sit amet pretium. Nam eu ipsum sit amet velit suscipit consectetur vel sit amet dolor. Sed ac aliquam est, dictum gravida est. Donec pellentesque condimentum est at bibendum. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nulla id urna non mauris faucibus fermentum. Phasellus quam ante, bibendum eget orci a, aliquam fringilla tortor. In vitae nulla nec leo tincidunt convallis. Integer ac ipsum a lorem sagittis pretium tincidunt id erat.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-12">
     
<img class="img-responsive" src="http://www.lpzoo.org/sites/default/files/images/multimedia/kapukikingnosetonose1200.jpg">
</div>
<div class="col-sm-12">
 <p>Duis maximus est nec eros euismod, quis volutpat magna pellentesque. Maecenas orci sapien, gravida quis commodo a, pharetra at sapien. Etiam scelerisque nunc sit amet ligula volutpat convallis. Nam egestas commodo tortor at pellentesque. Pellentesque vitae dictum urna. Etiam tincidunt magna et aliquam tincidunt. Vestibulum blandit arcu a pulvinar auctor. Phasellus malesuada, tortor sit amet mollis pulvinar, felis felis lacinia tellus, tempus ultricies urna magna et augue. Fusce ut ipsum eget odio sodales viverra. Morbi sit amet hendrerit purus, sit amet porttitor sapien. Quisque ut quam eu erat elementum lobortis. Proin sit amet nisl eget est feugiat vulputate. Morbi eu orci semper, rhoncus lacus eget, fringilla lorem.</p>
  </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `container-fluid` to achieve the desired result.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">

<style>
img {
  height: auto;
  width: 100%;
}
</style>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-1">
      Boo
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-11">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam sed ligula nec erat dapibus ullamcorper. Aliquam egestas, justo nec dictum vestibulum, dui eros ullamcorper mauris, non facilisis lorem ligula ut ex. Mauris scelerisque libero nulla, eget luctus velit fringilla ut. Etiam ut magna eget elit gravida ultrices. Quisque a enim id leo tincidunt lobortis. Pellentesque nulla mi, aliquet non mauris et, aliquam egestas leo. Nulla convallis tincidunt gravida. Suspendisse aliquam lacinia eros sit amet pretium. Nam eu ipsum sit amet velit suscipit consectetur vel sit amet dolor. Sed ac aliquam est, dictum gravida est. Donec pellentesque condimentum est at bibendum. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nulla id urna non mauris faucibus fermentum. Phasellus quam ante, bibendum eget orci a, aliquam fringilla tortor. In vitae nulla nec leo tincidunt convallis. Integer ac ipsum a lorem sagittis pretium tincidunt id erat.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
    
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <img src="http://www.lpzoo.org/sites/default/files/images/multimedia/kapukikingnosetonose1200.jpg">
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-1">
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-11">
      <p>Duis maximus est nec eros euismod, quis volutpat magna pellentesque. Maecenas orci sapien, gravida quis commodo a, pharetra at sapien. Etiam scelerisque nunc sit amet ligula volutpat convallis. Nam egestas commodo tortor at pellentesque. Pellentesque vitae dictum urna. Etiam tincidunt magna et aliquam tincidunt. Vestibulum blandit arcu a pulvinar auctor. Phasellus malesuada, tortor sit amet mollis pulvinar, felis felis lacinia tellus, tempus ultricies urna magna et augue. Fusce ut ipsum eget odio sodales viverra. Morbi sit amet hendrerit purus, sit amet porttitor sapien. Quisque ut quam eu erat elementum lobortis. Proin sit amet nisl eget est feugiat vulputate. Morbi eu orci semper, rhoncus lacus eget, fringilla lorem.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/glebkema/pn8jbk8p/